# How can I can a list of printers that use the generic/text only print driver?

Tags: c#, printing, visual-studio-2022

I'm writing a program in VS2022 to print a label to a Zebra printer installed with the generic/text only print driver.  Is there a way to get a list of only the printers that use this driver?

```
        private void PopulateInstalledPrintersCombo()
    {
        // Add list of installed printers found to the combo box.
        // The pkInstalledPrinters string will be used to provide the display string.
        String pkInstalledPrinters;
        for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
        {
            pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
            cbxPrinters.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters);
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but it returns ALL installed printers. I just want the Zebra printers installed with gneric/text only driver.  I can print to the Zebra using this IP address, but the user has to provide that info.  Having a pick-list would be a friendly way to do it.